# Remove string between two delimiter, inclusively

Tags: bash, sed

In a bash script, what utility and how do I go about removing text between two strings, inclusive of the stings.

Original text:

```
(ABC blah1)blah 2(def blah 5)blah 7)(DEF blah 8)blah 9
```

I would like to remove all text between '(def' and the next ')'.  So my desired output would be:

```
(ABC blah1)blah 2blah 7)blah 9
```

It would be preferable to have the search be case insensitive... in the above example, it found and remove '(def...)' and '(DEF...)'

I have tried:

```
echo "(ABC blah1)blah 2(def blah 5)blah 7)(DEF blah 8)blah 9" | sed 's/(def.*)//gI'
```

but the output is:

```
(ABC blah1)blah 2blah 9
```

I think this is because '.*' is greedy in sed.

Any ideas how I can format my sed search string?  Is sed even the best util for this?  I am running this from a bash script so anything basic util avail via bash will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, sed is greedy.  But you can do:

```
sed 's/(def[^)]*)//gi'
```

Note that not all sed accept the `i` flag, so you may need to do:

```
sed 's/([dD][eE][fF][^)]*)//g'
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks much.  BTW, my version of sed does accept 'i' so it saved on a few keystrokes.